# mod_rewrite - how do I match a URL, but not it's subdirectories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an ecommerce site, with product URLs in the following format: `site.com/product/long-product-title-here?sku=skugoeshere` and want it in this format: `site.com/product/long-product-title-here/skugoeshere`

One reason for the query is that each page could have multiple variations of the same product.

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to make it look nicer using the following:

```
  # RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sku=(.+)$
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} product/([^/]+)$
  # RewriteRule /([^/]+)$ /$1/%1 [R=301,L]
```

But this goes into a redirect loop of the form `site.com/product/title/title/title...`

How do I make the pattern only match the original URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+/[^/]+)\?sku=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)sku=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1?sku=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! The external redirect part works, but the internal forward does not, I get 404s. I tried to redirect a hardcoded url (products/title/sku) with no conditions and that didn't work either. I'm using Drupal so maybe it's something weird going on there.

Comment: When you enter `site.com/product/long-product-title-here?sku=skugoeshere` does it load properly?

Comment: Also do you have any other rules OR any other .htaccess?

Comment: I have other rules, and only the one .htaccess. Drupal creates some URL aliases of its own via PHP, but my other rules in .htaccess can rewrite to these just fine.

Comment: Just tried turning off Drupal's rewriting and using the default node/12345?sku=1234 path form and your code worked fine. Think I'll have to do this via PHP to keep it compatible with Drupal.

Comment: Oh ok I guess ordering of rules could have been issue. Thanks for your acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

skip the leading slash here

```
RewriteRule /([^/]+)$ $1/%1 [R=301,L]
                      ^ no slash here
```